# Is there a way (In PHP) of detecting if the script was called by jQuery load or not?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

I'd like a script that could detect if called by jquery

If not, it'd display the page+layout, if not, it'd just so the content (but that is irrelevant)

But yeah, a way of detecting if it was called by jquery load - ajax - or directly requested.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you not send a GET parameter with the load?

Ie:

```
jquery=1 //(for load)

jquery=2 //(for the 'low-level' ajax call)
```

Any other value for normal script load

Then you let the PHP script deal with determining what to do next. By reading the value of `$_GET['jquery']`

Comment: So if i have a script that says:
 $("#actualcontent").load($(this).attr("href"));

how would I add an extra variable/GET parameter to this?

Comment: $("#actualcontent").load($(this).attr("href")+'?jquery=1');

Comment: If overly manual. jQuery already sends something along with the request you can use without having to change a single line of JS.

Comment: I also vote for using `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` like the other answer.  After all, that's exactly what it's there for -- to see if the request was from an Ajax implementation.

Comment: Fair enough, but how will you differentiate from a jQuery load() call and jQuery ajax() call? As mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't think you're reading the question the same way. I don't see a need to distinguish between ajax() and load() in the question. You're reading it as "jQuery load, ajax, or direct" - I'm reading it as "jQuery load (i.e. ajax) or direct".

Answer (score 14):

You might want to take a look at the HTTP headers your server is receiving.

For instance, let's consider I have this page :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#test').load('temp.php');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the temp.php script contains only this :

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);

die;
```

When `load` is executed, the "test" `<div>` will contain the dump of `$_SERVER` ; and it'll include this, amongst other things :

```
'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => string 'XMLHttpRequest' (length=14)
```

[`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is the object that's used to make Ajax request.

This means you should be able to detect if the request was made via an AJax query, with something like this :

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    echo "Ajax";
} else {
    echo "Not Ajax";
}
```

With this, you can detect whether your page is called "normally", or via an Ajax request, and decide if you must include layout or not.

BTW : this is exactly the solution that's used by, for instance, Zend Framework, to [detect Ajax requests](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.ajax).

Comment: First line can be simplified to if (@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {

Comment: @Sbm007 : I really don't like to "hide" errors with the @ operator, and use it only when it's trully necessary -- here, I want to test if that entry in $_SERVER is present and if its value is what I want, and this is exactly what isset and the second condition do.

Comment: Oh okay fair enough, I was unaware of that. I thought they were the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: No need for isset nor the @ operator - `if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) { }` will do just fine. No need for the extra cruft.

Comment: @Sbm007 : no problem :-) ;; @ceejayoz : this way, when your PHP script is called normally (ie, when that entry doesn't exist in $_SERVER), you'll get a "Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" -- and yes, I always develop with notices activated, and I encourage everyone to do the same, on this one.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm remembering correctly, jQuery's AJAX functions send a `X-Requested-With` header (with a value of `XMLHttpRequest`).

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Zend Framework you could use

```
// in one of your controllers
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
  // ...
}
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html