# jquery $.get with auth expired: gets the login screen in popup

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, authentication, popup

the problem is that if the auth cookie has expired and the user clicks on a link that should open a popup using $.get than **i get the login screen in the popup** (same masterpage in another masterpage) **instead of redirecting the whole page to the login screen**

anybody knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Do you want the user to be redirected to the login page if she clicks on a link and the auth cookie is expired? Please clarify the question.

Comment: yes, I want the user to be redirected when he clicks on a link, and this is what usually happens, but when he clicks on a link that is jquery $.get wich returns a PartialViewResult into a popup than i get the login screen into the popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC has the following property on it's `Request` object:

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

This will (amongst other things) checks for the existence of the `X-Requested-With` header, and a value of `XMLHTTPRequest`. Checking this, along with checking for IsAuthenticated would allow you to modify your response appropriately.

What you do then is up to you:

1. Display a message to the user in the pop-up requesting that they log in again.
2. Handle the response and perform a redirect as per [Pekka's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070609/jquery-get-with-auth-expired-gets-the-login-screen-in-popup/2070637#2070637).

Answer (score 3):

When you make a request after your login session has expired ASP.NET will automatically do a 302 redirect to your login action instead of returning a 401 "Unauthorized". The browser will quietly follow the redirect (even during an AJAX request) and make a second request to bring down the login page.
There's no way that I am aware of to detect or prevent this redirect in Javascript and there's no way of prevent the redirect server-side without reimplementing the entire FormsAuthenticationModule.

However, jQuery inserts an HTTP header

```
X-Requested-With=XmlHttpRequest
```

when making Ajax calls. The Request.IsAjaxRequest() method in ASP.NET MVC can be used to detect the presence of this header.

What we do in our site is put

`if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}`

into our /auth/login action so that a 401 error is returned instead of the login page HTML if /auth/login is called during an AJAX call. We then detect the 401 in Javascript and redirect to the login page manually.

Unfortunately Firefox (as of 3.5) and Opera (as of ~9.something) do not maintain the X-Requested-With header in the second request after a redirect, so IsAjaxRequest() returns false in this situation when these browsers are being used. This wasn't a big issue for us but its something to keep in mind.

Comment: Here's what I do to overcome redirect issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588589/firefox-does-not-preserve-custom-headers-during-ajax-request-redirect-an-asp-net. It may fail to work on old IIS versions due to read-only headers; thus in the project I use custom flag in TempData and custom IsAjaxRequest like this: return controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() || controller.TempData.ContainsKey("__isajaxrequest").

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you do with the results of your $.get operation but you could do one of the following:

- Detect when your page is called through Ajax, and return a graceful error message
- Detect when your page is called through Ajax, and return a piece of JavaScript to redirect the whole page to the login page (`location.href=...`)

Check out [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482086/is-there-a-way-in-php-of-detecting-if-the-script-was-called-by-jquery-load-or-n) (the 2nd answer, preferably, mentioning the header) to find out how to detect whether a call was made using AJAX.

Comment: i have an action method that returns PartialView, the $.get calls this action method and puts this result into a div which is shown after this as a popup using jquery

Comment: Right. I'm not familiar with ASP/.net but the basic workings should be the same. Your login page should react if called through AJAX and return the right content, a script snippet changing the location should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the server has redirected you to a different login page, then you could check for the response headers (assuming they're being set) in your ajax callback, and see if the [http status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) is `3xx`. If it is, do a manual redirect.

The `$.get` call returns an `XMLHTTPRequest` object and the property to check in that object is `status`, or make use of the low-level `$.ajax` instead of `$.get`.

Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) for more approaches. Can't you change the response headers/status code when sending back the PartialView?

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend an approach similar to what is described here: http://developer.fellowshipone.com/patterns/#_logout_counter

Basically, inform the user their session is going to expire via a countdown. As soon as the session expires immediately redirect to the login page.